# How Pointer Array is used to store values of array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

The following code is the answer that I found to this challenge

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/vector-sort/problem?isFullScreen=true&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen

```
int main() {
      
    int x,y,s=0;
    cin>>x>>y;
    int *arr[x];
    while(x--)
    {
        int num;
        cin>>num;
        arr[s]=new int[num];
        for(int i = 0; i<num ; i++)
        {
            cin>>arr[s][i];
        }
        s++;
    }
    while(y--)
    {
        int a,b;
        cin>>a>>b;
        cout<<arr[a][b];
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    
     return 0;
}
```

My question is how "arr" which is a pointer array can store values of the array elements in line 13 and also print the array elements in line 21.

To use the value stored in the array we must use an asterisk right?
Then how is it possible to scan and print elements in the pointer array without an asterisk as a prefix?

Comment: `int *arr[x];` is not standard C++: [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard). I suggest you to learn about standard portable C++ before you dive into fancy compiler extensions, that would be `std::vector<int*> arr(x);` or `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` for 2d

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
      
    int size  ;
    cin>>size;
    int *array=new int [size];
 
 
 
 for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
    
 cout<< array[size]<<endl; //it will print zero beccause by default all values set to zero
    
    
 }   
}
```

so in this way we can use pointers. To declare pointer array

Answer (score -1):

[N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) 5.2.1 Subscripting says:

> The expression `E1[E2]` is identical (by definition) to `*((E1)+(E2))`

Therefore, `arr[s][i]` means `*(*(arr + s) + i)` and it can do what can be done with asterrisks.